# How to add a Layout / Design Exception programmatically

Tags: exception, magento, layout

I want to add an exception to the layout (as it is possible in www.url.de/admin/system_config/edit/section/design/ under the point themes). The thing is that I want to add this "add Exception" via code and not via the magento backend. 
Is there an easy way to do that?

Comment: It depends on what your exception criterion is / criteria are. Please add these details. The OOB exceptions are based on user agent headers and evaluated by `Mage_Core_Model_Design_Package` aka `core/design_package` class.

Comment: Thx for the answer. For example I want to add the exception "iPhone|iPod..." with the value "myDesignFolder" in the default-section of the themes. And I want to set this value via code not via backend.  Mage_Core_Model_Design_Package doesn't give me any kind of "setExceptionForDefault($matchedExpression, $value)"-function. You know what I mean? I need a function which I can call to add an theme-default-Exception in my own controller.

Answer (score 0):

*Based on the OP comment, the goal is to alter theme configuration for the configured default setting based on the module controller.*

This seems like a Bad Idea™. Changing theme configuration behind the scenes is going to be (1) ineffective or (2) confusing to the person administering the site.

1. If the design assets are being matched above the configured default field, the design exception will not apply
2. If the design exception does apply, it silently alters standard Magento design configuration modeling

If possible, it would be better (in your controller class or superclass) to add a custom handle to the `core/layout_update` object instance and then leverage the layout update system to do this.